# "How To Ask" text should link to help center, not faq

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, user-interface, help-center

Similar to my [question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189393/metas-how-to-ask-links-to-faq), Code Review's "*How To Ask*" text should link to the help center, rather than the FAQ:

[image: How To Ask: CR.SO]

Interestingly, CR's Meta seems to be more up to date than SO's:

[image: How To Ask: Meta.CR.SO]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expected this to require site-by-site edits, but thankfully this issue got attention of SE employees. The issue has been resolved via 'extreme SQL'. See [this answer](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/720/5454) for details.